# get GroupBy count in Dexie

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have an **IndexedDB** table that follows accepts following structured JSON as a row:

```
{
    id : 1,
    name : 'doc1',
    createdDate : '2018-08-08'
}
```

I want to get count for each available date in the table. ie: *groupby:date then count*. Expected example output is in the format of:

```
{
    '2018-08-08' : 5,
    '2018-08-18' : 19,
    ...
}
```

Table contains large number of records. So, how can efficiently achieve this requirement using Dexie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you index createdDate,

```js
const db = new Dexie("yourDB");
db.version(1).stores({
  yourTable: "id, name, createdDate"
});
```

Then you could do the following:

```js
const result = {}
await db.yourTable.orderBy('createdDate').eachKey(date => {
  result[date] = (result[date] || 0) + 1;
});
```